# Difference between $true and $false under the hood

Tags: powershell, boolean

So I was playing around with PowerShell a little and came across a somewhat surprising result in the following code

```
function returns_true(){
    return $true
}

function returns_false(){
    return $false
}

if (returns_true -eq $true){
    Write-Host "I return true"
}

if (returns_false -eq $false){
    Write-Host "I return false"
}
$myval = returns_false
Write-Host $myval
```

Running this gives me the following output

```
I return true
False
```

I was expecting this to return either

```
I return true
I return false
False
```

or just

```
False
```

Could someone explain what is going on here. What is PowerAhell doing under the hood that allows me to evaluate `-eq $true`, but not `-eq $false` when I return `$true` and `$false`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's actually happening here is that the parser is seeing -eq $true and -eq $false as arguments being passed to the functions.

To see that this is the case, add [CmdletBinding()]Param() to the functions like this:

```
function returns_true(){
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()
    return $true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I came across a few other surprising results when testing this out, but after you explained that, they all make sense now!

Comment: Another way to verify the unexpected behaviour: change the body to `$args` and it will return `-eq` and `$true` on seperate lines

Comment: @FrodeF.- good point.  I try to urge people to use CmdletBinding() almost always, so that's usually my go-to.

Answer (score 3):

Better explanation as to what's happening:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115149/9446818

Parentheses help. What you really want is:

```
if ((returns_true) -eq $true){
```

and

```
if ((returns_false) -eq $false){
```

Comment: Why? Because the `( )` around the function names instruct the parser that you want them evaluated as expressions.

Comment: Parens make it "work", but it's not obvious from looking at the code why that is the case.  I like understanding the parsing modes, but I recommend using CmdletBinding() and that makes it clear that the -eq is being treated as a parameter.